# Changing background-image once gif has loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

Ok so basically i'm using a gif as a background image, however i'd like it to display a static image until the gif has fully loaded and be ready to play.

Having read a few similar threads i know you can target elements with js and change them once they've loaded however the only examples i've seen target img tags and not a background image via css.

Heres a snippet if it helps

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #232228 url(../img/bg-center.jpg) top no-repeat; /* Static */
  background: #232228 url(../img/bg-center.gif) top no-repeat; /* Animated */
}
```

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29742508/show-loading-gif-while-image-is-loading

Comment: Im not using image tags though, ive seen a few posts about it with image tags but cant find anything to specifically target only the background image

Comment: You should use an regular image so you can use an onload Event. There are no DOM Events for a background-image.

Comment: Why not use a canvas, and just have it display your static image until the gif is ready? If you want the element as a background, just use the z-index to draw it in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid that you will have to use JS for this, use images loaded plugin to see if the gif image is loaded then change the bg property

Comment: hmm any idea why this isnt working?

`<script src="https://npmcdn.com/imagesloaded@4.1/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    imagesLoaded( '.bgloaded', { background: true }, function(document.body.className+='bgloaded') {
      console.log('body background image loaded');
    });

    </script>`

Comment: Can you give me a fiddle?

Comment: @IzaakLindsay see the updated fiddle, passing the className is the issue

Comment: yeah i got that, i was trying to add the function to add the bgloaded class to the body once that image had loaded

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vf4pcux9/8/

Its not waiting for the gif to load before adding the class

Comment: Sorry Don't have access to my pc