# show a spinner image while page inside div is loading and hide spinner image while the page completely loaded inside div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have this Menu list

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="width:80px;">
   <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">Profile</a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li id="profile"><a href="#">My Profile</a></li>
            <li id="drive"><a href="#">My Drive</a></li>
          </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

which i call `profile.php` and `drive.php` with this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#profile").click(function(){
        $("#box").load("/functions/profile.php");
    });    
    $("#drive").click(function(){
        $("#box").load("/functions/drive.php");
    }); 
});
```

into this `<div id="box"></div>` and it works great :).

But there is a problem because `profile.php` page has a large image and takes time to load. Therefore, i want to show a `laoding.gif` image into `<div id="box"></div>` while `profile.php` page loading in it, and when `profile.php` loaded completed then the `loading.gif` image should be hidden and the `profile.php` page should be visible in `<div id="box"></div>`.

Thanks in advance.

I am a student, so it is a bit difficult for me to solve it.

P.S. I search google a lot but none worked.

Comment: You could show your loading image before you call `.load()` and use the *complete-callback* of `.load()` to hide the image. See http://api.jquery.com/load/ for the API.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show loading gif while image is loading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29742508/show-loading-gif-while-image-is-loading)

Comment: Dear @mpf82 can you please guide me how to fix it.

Comment: Dear @samrodrigues it is not the answer i am looking for sorry. If think that it is then do provide me a clue. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
$("#box").html("<img src='laoding.gif' />").load("/functions/profile.php");
```

This will change the html from the #box element until the load function finishes and replaces again the content.

[Working example.](https://jsfiddle.net/wLmshtdm/4/)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried on my file but no luck. Please do check in Jsfiddle. Thanks. :)

Comment: Maybe you get a different error. There are any errors in the console?

Comment: This is what I have Same in my php file.  https://jsfiddle.net/wLmshtdm/3/

Comment: @qaisali could you provide a little more of the html  structure

Comment: You can't load codepen or google because you'll get No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. [Read here about it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource).